# When running my index.js I get: "File X cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system"

Tags: windows, powershell

```
PS C:\Users\Leff Tubat\express-demo> nodemon index.js
nodemon : File C:\Users\Leff Tubat\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.ps1 cannot
be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more
information, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ nodemon index.js
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

I tried ./index.js 3000 but it did not work out.

Comment: You need to be admin, to change the policy, by default you cannot run untrusted scripts in powershell

Comment: Read the error message, go to https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170 and read that page.

Comment: Hii, I just resolved the problem, thanks for y'all help! It really means a lot. I even executed the  Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted syntax to allow me to run the script.

Answer (score 0):

Open the powershell as administrator and run the following command

> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser